# Jquery Validator shows tooltip as error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate the form, below is the HTML code. The issue I'm facing is when I provide a tooltip irrespective of the type of error the validation message is shown as tooltip text.

I want the error message to say "Please enter at least 5 characters.". How can I achieve this?

```html
<div class="form-group" style="padding-right: 5px;">
  <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
  <div class="col-xs-5" style="width: auto;"><input name="name" id="name" type="text" minlength="5" title="please enter name" data-type="text" class="form-control"><span style="display: inline;"><label for="name" generated="true" class="invalidElem" style="display: inline-block;">please enter name</label></span></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and JS code in an example

Comment: You've shown us no attempt whatsoever to solve this issue yourself.

Comment: Tooltip?  I don't see a tooltip in your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rule and different message for rule  like below.

```js
$('#myform').validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5

    }

  },
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: 'Please Enter Name.',
      minlength: 'Please enter at least 5 characters.'

    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert('valid form submitted');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-group" style="padding-right: 5px;">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="width: auto;"><input name="name" id="name" type="text" minlength="5" title="please enter name" data-type="text" class="form-control"><span style="display: inline;"><label for="name" generated="true" class="invalidElem" style="display: inline-block;"> </label></span></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```